# How can i intent this code to another activity?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, intentfilter

How can I pass this code to my another activity, I created two activities one is home activity and another is video_activity I call this code in video_activity in bottom nav but I also want to call it on my home activity I tried too much by I am not getting the correct one and please help me ... I want to pass this code from video activity to home activity ...

```
 case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                    favourite = toolbar;
                    favourite.setTitle(item.getTitle().toString());
                    videos.clear();
                    fetch_db("favorit");
                    favouritList();

                    return true;
```

Comment: you can't pass code through intent. If you need same functonality in multiple classes - create a base class, and extend other classes from it.

Comment: how can i do .... i am new to android and get confused too much ... please help me out

Comment: `how can i do` what exactly is a problem? please note, I wont give you complete code as StackOverflow is not free code service. Specify what is the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a function and call it from other activities

**Example:**

```
public class A { 
public void foo(){ //your code ... } 
}
```

In other activities:

```
A namefunction = new A();  
namefunction.foo();
```

Or you can use the static method

Here are several instructions you may want to look:  [link 1](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) , [link 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)